# Is there a way in OpenLayers to render EPSG:3857 tiles on an EPSG:4326 map?

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-6, vector-tiles, proj4js

I have a map in the `EPSG:4326` projection, and I'd like to use an `EPSG:3857` tileset such as the one from Mapbox. However, I've so far not been able to make it work.

In [this discussion](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/6059#issuecomment-315525946) ahocevar explains that arbitrary reprojection of vector tiles is not supported or planned because the vector clipping would be complex and introduce artifacts from curved clip-paths. The 3857 and 4326 are square relative to each other, but the code to support reprojecting between the two would complexify the library.

ahocevar also mentions a workaround involving image tiles sourced from a hidden map. However, this doesn't make sense because in any case, 3857 tiles do not line up with a 4326 tile grid, because no amount of transformation can change where the tile boundaries are.

I know there are examples of rendering to an offscreen canvas and using Mapbox GL, but both of these aren't ideal because they are going around the library (e.g. it doesn't work with `map.getFeaturesAtPixel`). I'm wondering if openlayers itself has a way to do this.

Here is an attempt: https://codesandbox.io/s/mvt-3857-to-4326-attempt-qsf07

Here's the relevant code:

```js
const mapboxSource = new VectorTileSource({
        attributions: '© <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/map-feedback/">Mapbox</a> ' +
            '© <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">' +
            'OpenStreetMap contributors</a>',
        projection: 'EPSG:4326',
        tileUrlFunction: (tileCoord) => {
            // Use the tile coordinate as a pseudo URL for caching purposes
            return JSON.stringify(tileCoord);
        },
        tileLoadFunction: async (tile, urlToken) => {
            const tileCoord = JSON.parse(urlToken);
            console.log('tileCoord', tileCoord);
            const [z, x, y] = tileCoord;

            const tileUrl = url
                .replace('{z}', String(z))
                .replace('{x}', String(x))
                .replace('{y}', String(y))
                .replace('{a-d}', 'abcd'.substr(((x << z) + y) % 4, 1))
            ;

            try {
                const response = await fetch(tileUrl);
                if (!response.ok) throw new Error();
                const arrayBuffer = await response.arrayBuffer();

                // Transform the vector tile's arrayBuffer into features and add them to the tile.
                const {layers} = new VectorTile(new Protobuf(arrayBuffer));
                const geojsonFeatures = [];
                Object.keys(layers).forEach((layerName) => {
                    const layer = layers[layerName];
                    for (let i = 0, len = layer.length; i < len; i++) {
                        const geojson = layer.feature(i).toGeoJSON(x, y, z);
                        geojson.properties.layer = layerName;
                        geojsonFeatures.push(geojson);
                    }
                });

                const features = geojsonFormat.readFeatures({
                    type: 'FeatureCollection',
                    features: geojsonFeatures,
                });
                tile.setFeatures(features);
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
                debugger;
                tile.setState(TileState.ERROR);
            }
        },
```

This only loads z:0 correctly. As soon as you zoom in, the MVT layer no longer aligns with the OSM base map.

I also experimented with drawing straight to TileImages with `toContext`, but couldn't figure out the mapping from coordinates to tile pixels, and the raster reprojection looked pretty blurry anyway. So I gave up and just used Maptiler's 4326 tileset, but I'd like to settle this question. Is it possible to render 3857 tiles on a 4326 map?

Thank you

Comment: Proof that it is possible to render EPSG:3857 vector tiles an EPSG:4326 map https://codesandbox.io/s/drag-and-drop-custom-mvt-forked-2jr6n

Comment: I wrote an a question (which some answers) some years ago on our sister site about gis (links on top right icon). In short: open layers and leaflets have different convention on z, and I had to do an additional patch (but trivial one) to the server side.

Comment: @Mike yes it's easy to draw an individual tile to a VectorLayer. But what I need is to integrate it with a Tile layer so that openlayers manages the loading of the tiles. If not then I have to manage the tile loading manually based on view state, so I might as well just draw to a canvas like the [offscreen-canvas](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/offscreen-canvas.html) or [mapbox-layer](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/mapbox-layer.html) examples. But I was hoping it could do it within OpenLayers with VectorTile/ImageTile layers somehow.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi is this the question?: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/180356/how-to-convert-non-web-mercator-coordinates-to-the-tile-y-x-z-coordinates

Comment: @Matthias: yes, so you see you need to correct x,y,z in openlayer (but it may depend on the backend). So: I was able to do it (and I like it more on large scale), but it seems that there is not much support (or just never tested)

Comment: @Matthias If it can be done for one tile it can be done for all tiles in the view extent https://codesandbox.io/s/vector-tile-info-forked-wtqxk  To maintain a styleable vector format after reprojection it needs to be a Vector layer (using the MVT `featureClass: Feature` option to overcome the coordinates to tile pixels issue) as tile grids must have the same tile size within a zoom level, which would not be the case if you attempted to use a grid from one projection as tiles in another projection.

Comment: @Mike that looks like a working solution! If you want to make it into an Answer for internet points I'll accept it. How did you figure that out? Also I assume you're mike-000 on GitHub -- I read through a few of your posts on ol issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it can be done for one tile as in https://codesandbox.io/s/drag-and-drop-custom-mvt-forked-2jr6n it can be done for all tiles in the view extent.  To maintain a styleable vector format after reprojection it needs to be a Vector layer (using the MVT `featureClass: Feature` option to overcome the coordinates to tile pixels issue) as tile grids must have the same tile size within a zoom level, which would not be the case if you attempted to use a grid from one projection as tiles in another projection.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.6.1/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <style>
      html, body, .map {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.6.1/build/ol.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

let map;
const format = new ol.format.MVT({ featureClass: ol.Feature });

const vectorTileSource = new ol.source.VectorTile({
  format: format,
  url:
    "https://basemaps.arcgis.com/v1/arcgis/rest/services/World_Basemap/VectorTileServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}.pbf"
});
const tileGrid = vectorTileSource.getTileGrid();

const vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector();
const vectorSources = [];

function loader(zoom) {
  const loadedTiles = [];
  return function (extent, resolution, projection) {
    const tileProjection = vectorTileSource.getProjection();
    const maxExtent = ol.proj.transformExtent(
      tileProjection.getExtent(),
      tileProjection,
      projection
    );
    const safeExtent = ol.extent.getIntersection(extent, maxExtent);
    const gridExtent = ol.proj.transformExtent(safeExtent, projection, tileProjection);
    tileGrid.forEachTileCoord(gridExtent, zoom, function (tileCoord) {
      const key = tileCoord.toString();
      if (loadedTiles.indexOf(key) < 0) {
        loadedTiles.push(key);
        fetch(vectorTileSource.getTileUrlFunction()(tileCoord))
          .then(function (response) {
            return response.arrayBuffer();
          })
          .then(function (result) {
            const features = format.readFeatures(result, {
              extent: tileGrid.getTileCoordExtent(tileCoord),
              featureProjection: tileProjection
            });
            features.forEach(function (feature) {
              feature.getGeometry().transform(tileProjection, projection);
            });
            vectorSources[zoom].addFeatures(features);
          })
          .catch(function () {
            loadedTiles.splice(loadedTiles.indexOf(key), 1);
          });
      }
    });
  };
}

tileGrid.getResolutions().forEach(function (resolutiom, zoom) {
  vectorSources.push(
    new ol.source.Vector({
      loader: loader(zoom),
      strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox
    })
  );
});

map = new ol.Map({
  target: "map",
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 2,
    projection: "EPSG:4326"
  }),
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    }),
    vectorLayer
  ]
});

let zoom;
function setSource() {
  const newZoom = Math.round(map.getView().getZoom());
  if (newZoom !== zoom && newZoom < vectorSources.length) {
    zoom = newZoom;
    vectorLayer.setSource(vectorSources[zoom]);
  }
}

map.getView().on("change:resolution", setSource);

setSource();

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Mike, this is workable. There is a minor amount of overlap at the edges and corners, so it seems like this would cause issues with transparency. Also if polygons have strokes (as in the default style), this will show the outline of the tiles. Still with these limitations it's more than good enough. Thanks again.

Comment: It seems that the tiles will keep accumulating in memory as the user browses the map, is that right? The source is changed between zoom levels which makes the features disappear for a bit. Would it be possible to use one source with some sort of tile management strategy?

Comment: That avoids any reloading of tiles.  If memory is problem you could instead call `source.clear()` when the view zoom level changes and reset the `loadedTiles` array.  To avoid edge effects you would need to put each tile in a separate layer with a layer extent (the tile extent in view projection) specified, which would be inefficient and difficult to manage.